# use a created function within a function vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

Im Making a VBA function to calculate an integral using the trapezoidal rule 
but how can I apply a function that I created in VBA to Use in a another Function...heres My Code ( the worksheet.function did not work)

```
Option Explicit

Function funcion(x As Double) As Double
    funcion = 3 * (x ^ 3) + 5 * (x ^ 2) - 10 * x + 20
End Function

Function Sumatoria(a As Double, n As Double, h As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sum As Double

    i = 0
    sum = 0

    Do While (i <= n - 1)
        sum = sum + WorksheetFunction.funcion(a + i * h)
         i = i + 1
    Loop

    Sumatoria = sum

 End Function
```

Comment: Just remove `WorksheetFunction` from the call.  Eg `sum = sum + funcion(a + i * h)`

Comment: Or maybe it is just a typo? `funcion` which should be `function` as what you explained in your question? also, CuberChase is right, you can call the function outright. Just include the function routine in your module.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
Function Sumatoria(a As Double, n As Double, h As Double) As Double

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim temp As Double

    i = 0
    sum = 0

    Do While (i <= n - 1)
        temp = a + i * h
        sum = sum + funcion(temp)
         i = i + 1
    Loop

    Sumatoria = sum

 End Function
```